# User/Profile access to Organization fields (IsSandbox) in Flow

Tags: permissions, sandbox, visual-flows, context, organization

I have a Flow that checks the Organization field "isSandbox" to determine whether or not to email a test address or a real address. However, when logged in as a non-admin user, this field is not accessible.

Is there a way around this or a better way to implement this?

```
FAST LOOKUP: orgType
Find all Organization records where:
Id Is null false
Sort records by: Id (Ascending)
Store the values of these fields in orgType: Id, IsSandbox
Result
Failed to find records.
________________________________________
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: sObject type 'Organization' is not supported.. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
```

Comment: You need to have 'View Setup and Configuration' enabled on the profile level to access Organization object and customer portal users can't access this object.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will probably refrain from doing so, since that would be a little too much access for what I would like to achieve. The solution posted in the answers did work out for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the Spring '20 release, you can set a flow version to always run in **system context**, bypassing the limited object/field permissions of the running user.  (Assuming you're not depending on user permissions to hide/show different fields to different users, etc...)

Steps:

> 1. Open the flow in Flow Builder.
> 2. Click **View properties**.
> 3. Click **Show Advanced**.
> 4. For **How to Run the Flow**, select **System Context with Sharing—Enforces Record-Level Access**.

If you choose system context with sharing, the flow respects org-wide default settings, role hierarchies, sharing rules, manual sharing, teams, and territories. But it doesn’t respect object permissions, field-level access, or other permissions of the running user.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_system_mode.htm&type=5